# Configure MassTransit for testing with WebApplicationFactory<Startup>

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, integration-testing, masstransit, rawrabbit

I have an ASP.NET Core web app and test setup using `WebApplicationFactory` to test my controller actions. I used RawRabbit before and it was easy enough for me to mock the `IBusClient` and add it to the DI container as a singleton. Within the `WebApplicationFactory<TStartup>.CreateWebHostBuilder()` I call this extension method to add my mocked `IBusClient` instance like so;

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Configures the service bus.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="webHostBuilder">The web host builder.</param>
/// <returns>A web host builder.</returns>
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureTestServiceBus(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder)
{
    webHostBuilder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IBusClient, MY_MOCK_INSTANCE>
    });

    return webHostBuilder;
}
```

But there are gaps in RawRabbit right now that made me decide to move over to MassTransit. However, I am wondering if there's already a better way to register the `IBus` into my container without mocking it inside my test. Not sure if `InMemoryTestFixture`, `BusTestFixture`, or `BusTestHarness` is the solution to my problem. Not sure how to use them together and what they do.

By the way, in my ASP.NET Core app, I have a reusable extension method setup like the code below to hook me up to RabbitMQ on startup.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Adds the service bus.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">The services.</param>
/// <param name="configurator">The configurator.</param>
/// <returns>A service collection.</returns>
public static IServiceCollection AddServiceBus(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceCollectionConfigurator> configurator)
{
    var rabbitMqConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("/app/configs/service-bus.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

    // Setup DI for MassTransit.
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
    {
        configurator(x);

        // Get the json configuration and use it to setup connection to RabbitMQ.
        var rabbitMQConfig = rabbitMqConfig.GetSection(ServiceBusOptionsKey).Get<RabbitMQOptions>();

        // Add bus to the container.
        x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Host(
                new Uri(rabbitMQConfig.Host),
                hostConfig =>
                {
                    hostConfig.Username(rabbitMQConfig.Username);
                    hostConfig.Password(rabbitMQConfig.Password);
                    hostConfig.Heartbeat(rabbitMQConfig.Heartbeat);
                });

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);

            // Add Serilog logging.
            cfg.UseSerilog();
        }));
    });

    // Add the hosted service that starts and stops the BusControl.
    services.AddSingleton<IMessageDataRepository, EncryptedMessageDataRepository>();
    services.AddSingleton<IEndpointNameFormatter, EndpointNameFormatter>();
    services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusHostedService>();

    return services;
}
```

Comment: Also, fyi, this is already added by MT: `services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());`

Comment: @PlatypusMaximus did you figure this out? I am also in the same situation as you were. I am using WebApplicationFactory and my API startup has my MassTransit config. I need to replace that config with the test harness but I don't know how to do that and cannot find anything online that shows me how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @frank-hale, did you solve this?

Comment: @mslot I was able to get this to work. I will post my repo here later. I need to set it up on GH.

Comment: @mslot, no I didn't solve it

Comment: @RyanMAd please do!!

Comment: Clone my project repo and checkout this [file](https://github.com/secret-agent-B/devkit-dotnet-core/blob/main/src/tests/Logistics.Orders.Test/OrdersIntegrationTestBase.cs). This will show you how I got my stuff wired up easily for testing and for production using `IBusRegistry`. This is my framework for building microservices using .NET Core 5.0.

Comment: Sorry, updated link [here](https://github.com/secret-agent-B/devkit-dotnet-core/blob/master/src/tests/Logistics.Orders.Test/OrdersIntegrationTestBase.cs)

Comment: Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a method from within my WebApplicationFactory like so;

```
    public void ConfigureTestServiceBus(Action<IServiceCollectionConfigurator> configurator)
    {
        this._configurator = configurator;
    }
```

Giving me the ability to register test handlers from within my derived integration class constructor;

```
    public Intg_GetCustomers(WebApplicationTestFactory<Startup> factory)
        : base(factory)
    {
        factory.ConfigureTestServiceBus(c =>
        {
            c.AddConsumer<TestGetProductConsumer>();
        });
    }
```

This configurator gets used when I call my extension method to add an InMemory instance of MassTransit

```
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureTestServiceBus(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder, Action<IServiceCollectionConfigurator> configurator)
{
    return webHostBuilder
        .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            // UseInMemoryServiceBus DI for MassTransit.
            services.AddMassTransit(c =>
            {
                configurator?.Invoke(c);

                // Add bus to the container.
                c.AddBus(provider =>
                {
                    var control = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
                    });

                    control.Start();

                    return control;
                });
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IMessageDataRepository, InMemoryMessageDataRepository>();
        });
}
```

Comment: But how do you replace the Bus registered in the application with the in-memory one? As you can only call `services.AddMassTransit` once.

Answer (score 3):

A MassTransit config defined during Startup could be replaced with a new configuration with custom WebApplicationFactory by removing services from MassTransit namespace, e.g.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>  
{   
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder) 
    {
      builder.ConfigureServices(services => 
      {
          var massTransitHostedService = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IHostedService) &&
                    d.ImplementationFactory != null &&
                    d.ImplementationFactory.Method.ReturnType == typeof(MassTransitHostedService)
                );
           services.Remove(massTransitHostedService);
           var descriptors = services.Where(d => 
                  d.ServiceType.Namespace.Contains("MassTransit",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                     .ToList();
         foreach (var d in descriptors) 
         {
           services.Remove(d);
         }     

         services.AddMassTransitInMemoryTestHarness(x =>
         {
           //add your consumers (again)
         });
      });
   }
}
```

Then your test could look like

```
public class TestClass : IClassFixture<CustomApplicationFactory> 
 {
    private readonly CustomApplicationFactoryfactory;

    public TestClass(CustomApplicationFactoryfactory)
    {
      this.factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]    
    public async Task TestName()
    {   
      CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(5000).Token;  
      var harness = factory.Services.GetRequiredService<InMemoryTestHarness>();
      await harness.Start();

      var bus = factory.Services.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>();
      try
      {
        await bus.Publish<MessageClass>(...some message...);      
        
        bool consumed = await harness.Consumed.Any<MessageClass>(cancellationToken);
        //do your asserts
      }
      finally
      {
        await harness.Stop();
      }
    }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to use the `InMemoryTestHarness`, so that you can ensure your message contracts can be serialized, your consumers are configured properly, and that everything works as expected. While some might call this an integration test, it's really just doing a proper test. And it's extremely quick, since it's all in-memory.

You can see a unit test [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Tests/Testing/ConsumerTest_Specs.cs#L23), but a short example is also shown below.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class When_a_consumer_is_being_tested
{
    InMemoryTestHarness _harness;
    ConsumerTestHarness<Testsumer> _consumer;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public async Task A_consumer_is_being_tested()
    {
        _harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();
        _consumer = _harness.Consumer<Testsumer>();

        await _harness.Start();

        await _harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(new A());
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public async Task Teardown()
    {
        await _harness.Stop();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_have_called_the_consumer_method()
    {
        _consumer.Consumed.Select<A>().Any().ShouldBe(true);
    }


    class Testsumer :
        IConsumer<A>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<A> context)
        {
            await context.RespondAsync(new B());
        }
    }


    class A
    {
    }


    class B
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this being useful when testing individual components. But is `InMemoryTestHarness` something that can be used for integration testing with a `WebApplicationFactory`?

Comment: I have an integration test runs an instance of my ASP.NET Core web app from `WebApplicationFactory` and then execute `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` through an HttpClient. The example above illustrates how I'd mock-up `IBusClient` from `RawRabbit` and then register it into my container using `IWebHostBuilder.ConfigureTestServices` method. I am wondering if I should just do the same thing for `IBus`. I was just wondering if that is something that is already available.

Comment: I'll probably create a new version of AddServiceBus like the one above that uses the In-Memory Bus

Comment: I guess I don't entirely understand what `InMemoryBus` is and how to utilize it.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the unit tests in MassTransit (one of them is linked above). It's a fully functional bus instance, but entirely in-memory for unit testing.

Comment: @PlatypusMaximus did you figure this out? I am also in the same situation as you were. I am using WebApplicationFactory and my API startup has my MassTransit config. I need to replace that config with the test harness but I don't know how to do that and cannot find anything online that shows me how to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @FrankHale did you find out? In my case I actually want to use a container instead of the harness but the IBus doesnt seem to start so the messages are never consumed.

Comment: @sharpc, I did not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (I'm injecting everywhere IPublishEndpoint interface only) I have just simply registered another IPublishEndpoint in ConfigureTestServices method like so:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class TastyTests
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory;
    private readonly InMemoryTestHarness harness = new();

    public TastyTests()
    {
        factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(serviceProvider =>
                {
                    return harness.Bus;
                });
            });
        });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        await harness.Start();
        try
        {
            var client = factory.CreateClient();
            const string url = "/endpoint-that-publish-message";

            var content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            (await harness.Published.Any<IMessage>()).Should().BeTrue();
        }
        finally
        {
            await harness.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```